# How does the elixir community recommend setting up integration tests with chromedriver?

Tags: testing, elixir, selenium-chromedriver, phoenix-framework

I am using Hound (https://github.com/HashNuke/hound) for integration testing a Phoenix application. I have chrome and chrome headless working. To get it working I have another terminal window running `chromedriver` (installed via brew). This feels odd to me. Is there a library or test setup that would feel more "integrated" into the application? What's the Elixir way of doing this?

In the Ruby world there's the `webdrivers` gem (https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers). As far as I know it downloads a specified driver (lets say chromedriver) to $HOME. Then with every test run, the test uses the driver downloaded to that destination to execute the tests.

Before the `webdrivers` gem there was `chromedriver-helper` gem. Before that it was phantomjs. These implementations made it so running integration tests required 1: downloading the driver 2: running the test

In Elixir (with Hound) I have my tests working by first running `chromedriver --verbose` in a terminal split, and in the other screen I run `mix test`. This works fine but feels disjointed. This adds extra steps, 1: download the driver 2: start the driver 3: run the test 4: stop driver

I could write a script manually to run chromedriver in the background, and stop it after the tests are run.

I am new to the Elixir community and so I've researched a lot. It's still not clear to me if there is a "traveled path" I should go down vs just hooking everything up manually.

Have I missed a recommended abstraction? Is this intentional? Is this "just not created, yet"?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out wallaby? See https://github.com/keathley/wallaby

Comment: indeed i have. seems to be less "star"ed on github then Hound, perhaps implying adoption? when i did consider it i think i saw docs implying that phantomjs needed to be running in another terminal window (or background?) so that integration tests could work, so essentially i'm still not sure why that's a step or has not been abstracted away.